# Adding software as one of the type-ahead options in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: menu, appmenu, menu-bar

I have **Kalzium** installed and would like it to also show up as an option when I do a type-ahead in Ubuntu 20.04.

Example:  When I do a type-ahead for `periodic` I get these options:
[image: Software apps]

How can I get it so Kalzium also shows as one of the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu search (Gnome Shell search) not only searches program name, but also generic names, comments and keywords in the program launcher to search. "Periodic Table" therefore may not be included in the launcher for Kalzium.

To add these keywords, customize the launcher of Kalzium. Desktop launchers are little text files ending with the `.desktop` extension that live in specific folders in your system, in `/usr/share/applications` for applications installed using the APT system, but elsewhere for applications installed as snap or flatpak.

Find the `.desktop` file of Kalzium, and make a copy of it in the `.local/share/applications` folder in your home directory. `.local` is a hidden folder that you only can see when you enable "Show hidden files" in the file manager.

Edit that copy, and edit, or add, `periodic table;` to the `Keywords=` line, so it looks similar to:

```
Keywords=chemistry;Mendeleev;periodic table;
```

Formatting is important: keywords are separated by semi-colon (`;`) and also the last keyword needs to end with a semi-colon.

Your local customized copy will take precedence over the system wide one. The launcher of Kalzium should now be found if you type "periodic".

If you want this change to apply for all users, then place the modified copy in `/usr/local/share/applications`. That folder does not exist by default, so you need to create it. This is better practice than directly editing the file in `/usr/share/applications`: that folder is managed by the operating system, and your changes may be overwritten by an update.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't have any `Keywords` in the Keywords field.  Once I added that to the *.desktop file it found it.